# Symfony2 - Trouble getting search method working as a service

Tags: php, symfony, search, service, doctrine-orm

I believe the problem lies in how I am calling my search service within the controller. The stand-alone search method works fine if I put it in directly into my controller.

If I do a dump on $results (from the search class) I can see the search function is working as intended. Yet when I'm calling it in my controller and passing it to twig it's not working and coming up blank.

**Side note:** when I pass in 'query' for the for loop {% for result in query %} it comes up blank if try to use 'results' instead I get the following error:

*"Impossible to access an attribute ("title") on a string variable ("practice") in AcmeProjectBundle:Default:search.html.twig at line 25)".*

**config.xml**

```
services:

search:
    class: Acme\ProjectBundle\Services\Search
    arguments: ["@request_stack", @doctrine]
    scope: request
```

**Search class (service)**

```
class Search
{
protected $request;

public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack, Registry $doctrine)
{
    $this->request = $requestStack->getCurrentRequest();
    $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
}

public function search()
{
    $results = null;
    $query = $this->request->query->get('q');

    if (!empty($query)) {
        $em = $this->doctrine->getManager();


        $results = $em->createQueryBuilder()
            ->from('AcmeProjectBundle:Blog', 'b')
            ->select('b')
            ->where('b.title LIKE :search')
            ->setParameter('search', "%${query}%")
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
    }
//        exit(\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($results));
    return array(
        'query'   => $query,
        'results' => $results,
    );
}
}
```

**SearchAction controller**

```
public function searchAction(Request $request)
{
    // Calling from the service Search
    $query = $this->get('search');
    $results = $query->search();

 //        exit(\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($query));
    return $this->render('AcmeProjectBundle:Default:search.html.twig', array(
        'query'        => $query,
        'results'      => $results,
    ));
}
```

**search.html.twig**

```
{% block search %}
<form action="{{ path('acme_project_search') }}" method="GET">
    <label><input type="search" name="q" value={{ app.request.query.get('q') }}></label>
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
<br>
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
{% for result in query %}
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8 blog-main">
            <div class="blog-post">
                <h2 class="blog-post-title">{{ result.title }}</h2>
                <p class="blog-post-meta"><time datetime="{{ result.created|date('c') }}">{{ result.created|date('l, F j, Y') }}</time> by <a href="#">{{ result.author }}</a></p>
                <p>{{ result.blog|truncate(350, true) }}</p><br>
                <div class="tags">
                    <p><strong>Tags: </strong><span class="highlight">{{ result.tags }}</span></p>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.blog-post -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: have you set your service in `app/config/config.yml` properly? Can you show it?

Comment: Sure thing, added/updated.

Comment: so the service is working well? At least you can call it right?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors and when I dump $query I get "public '__CLASS__' => string 'Acme\ProjectBundle\Services\Search ...", so it seems it's working. It's just nothing is coming up from the search when I enter in a title to search for. (when I use query in the for loop -- see twig file)

Comment: i think i figured out the problem, i post an answer now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, in your `SearchController`  and `SearchAction` method, you do

```
$results = $query->search();
```

But in your `Search` class you are returning an array instead of `$results`, and then you are returning it same way in the controller

**Search class (service)**

```
return array(
     'query'   => $query,
     'results' => $results,
);
```

**SearchController**

```
return $this->render('AcmeProjectBundle:Default:search.html.twig', array(
     'query'        => $query,
     'results'      => $results, // <----- this is an array already!
));
```

***Possible solutions***

one solution is to just return `$results` in you **Service** but then you would miss the query string

**OR**

another solution is to just set `$results` as return parameter in your `Controller`. This way:

```
return $this->render('AcmeProjectBundle:Default:search.html.twig', $results));
```

**OR**

this solutions is more suitable in case you want to add other element to the return array.

```
return $this->render('AcmeProjectBundle:Default:search.html.twig', array(
     'query'        => $results['query'],
     'results'      => $results['results'],
));
```

Comment: Not sure I am following, I am returning $results in the search() for the service. What do I need to do? In the controller yes, I am returning them again as it's shown in the service.

Comment: I'd suggest the last solution :)

Comment: Gotcha, the last solution worked like a charm! Thank you Ponciste!

Answer (score 1):

Search:search returns an associative array with the two keys 'query' and 'results'.
You pass this array as a return value to twig in another associative array with the two keys 'query' and 'results' for 'results'.

So your array in twig looks like

```
array {
    'query' => [Search instance]
    'results' => array(
        'query' => [Query instance]
        'results' => [results]
    )
}
```

in the foreach loop, you would need to access results.results this way.

I dont think, that you need the Search class instance or the Query instance in twig, so perhaps just return the results array from the search method, and pass them over to twig so use your foreach based on 'results' and access the single members during foreach simply with result.title and so on?